# Java HTTP request message

Tags: java, http

In Java, how can I construct an HTTP request message to get a resource specified by a request URI that a user inputs after I've opened up a socket to connect with a server?

If anyone could just point me to an article with the general tools I would need, that would be cool too. Thank you!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best low-level reference is the [HTTP/1.1 Specification](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616.html), which describes in detail all possible aspects of an HTTP request message.

If you're not actually interested in building the request yourself, the [java.net.URL](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) class contains everything you need.

Comment: The low level reference was what I was looking for. Your other link will help me out in the future. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Apache [HttpClient](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/), in particular [HttpGet](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpGet.html):

```
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
responseBody = httpClient.execute(httpGet, handler);
```